# Use PHP to parse aspx

Tags: php, asp.net, parsing

Let's see this page http://bet.hkjc.com/football/default.aspx?ci=en-US

In this page, if I click on any link, the URL is the same (no change).
So, if I want to parse/view source code, the html is not the same as I want.
Then, how to get a real URL and view the correct source code so that I can parse the page?

Comment: you can do it with CURL, but may need the help of firebug, or fidler to inspect the form parameters when you click some links/buttons, that is with regular postback.

Comment: here is a quick tutorial of CURL http://www.higherpass.com/php/Tutorials/Using-Curl-To-Query-Remote-Servers/, the idea is using fidler, or firebug you will inspect the form values submitted when you click and link on the page, and set those values to CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS

Answer (score 3):

The short answer is that you don't. ASPX, just like PHP is processed on the server and never sent to the visitor, so you will not get the source.

---

The page includes the content in iFrames. You can get the content by following the urls in the iFrames.

On that specific webpage, all the display HTML is created through javascript, which is used to massage the data in an array which you can find in the source file of the iFrame (see http://bet.hkjc.com/football/index.aspx?lang=ch for instance).

Assuming that you are only interested in the data and not the formatting details, all you have to do is figure out how the array is organized and simply import the array. No need to parse the HTML at all.

Now, the real question is whether or not you are authorized to use the content. It's copyrighted by default, so unless you have an explicit permission, you should really consider whether your use of this content falls under the terms of fair use. If you plan to display the content on your website, this is definitely not "fair use" and you have no right to do so.

Answer (score 2):

Looks like the page uses Javascript to load new content. That is why the url does not change. If you find out where the content is loaded from you could get it from there too.

Use [Firebug](https://addons.mozilla.org/en/firefox/addon/firebug/) and watch the network tab to find the right url.

Comment: Use Firebug can get the actual URL?

Comment: Yes you can. But it loads quite a lot so it will take a while to find the right page.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use a combination of DOM monitoring (like via firebug) and HTTP request monitoring (like with "Live HTTP Headers" plugin).  This will allow you to monitor the traffic being generated between the client side javascript and the server itself both via AJAX style calls and user initiated calls (form submits etc.)

ASPX maintains sessions using a several techniques that you will need to emulate with your php code and curl or similar.  This can be tricky indeed.

Also note that you might need to keep a close eye on the HTTP header - depending on how the server is setup, it may reject your request wholesale if it doesn't match precisely.